# Determining Class of a general Borel measure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, and $\Sigma = \Sigma(\mathcal{T})$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets (that is, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{T}$).

In *Real Analysis and Probability* by R. M. Dudley, I have the following definition: Call $\mathcal{C} \subset \Sigma$ a *determining class* for $(X,\Sigma)$ if: $\mathcal{C}$ generates $\Sigma$ and whenever measures $\mu$ and $\pi$ take equal, finite values on $\mathcal{C}$, then $\mu = \pi$.

The author goes on to show that sufficient conditions for $\mathcal{C}$ to be a determining class are that $X$ is a countable union of elements of $\mathcal{C}$ AND that $\mathcal{C}$ is a *semiring*: that is, $\emptyset \in \mathcal{C}$ and for any pair of sets $A, B \in \mathcal{C}$, $A\cap B \in \mathcal{C}$ and $A \backslash B$ is a finite union of disjoint elements of $\mathcal{C}$. In particular, these conditions are used to show that a measure defined on the finite-length half-open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ has a unique extension to the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

An alternative sufficient condition is that $\mathcal{C}$ is a *ring*: that is, $\emptyset \in \mathcal{C}$ and for any pair of sets $A, B \in \mathcal{C}$, $A\cup B \in \mathcal{C}$ and $A \backslash B \in \mathcal{C}$.

However, neither of these conditions are particularly topological; no collection of open and closed sets form a ring or a semiring for a general topological space (or even over $\mathbb{R}$). My question is as follows: is there a canonical way to construct a determining class for $(X,\Sigma)$? If not in general, is it possible in special cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the following formulation:

For a system of sets $\mathscr{E}$ which generates the $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathscr{A}$ on $\Omega$ and is closed under $\cap$ and contains a sequence $(E_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\Omega = \bigcup_n^\infty E_n$. Then two measures $\mu, \nu$ which satisfy
$$\mu(E) = \nu(E) \qquad E\in \mathscr{E}$$
and
$$\mu(E_n) = \nu(E_n) < \infty \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}$$
are identical.

Proof: Let $\mathscr{E}'$ be the system of sets $E \in \mathscr{E}: \mu(E) =
\nu(E)<\infty.$ Now, for $E\in \mathscr{E}'$ consider
\begin{align*}
 \mathscr{D}_E:=\left\{ D\in \mathscr{A}: \mu(E\cap D) = \nu(E\cap D) \right\}
\end{align*}
It is straigt forward to show that $\mathscr{D}_E$ is a Dynkin System. Since
$\mathscr{E}$ is closed under $\cap$: $\mathscr{E}\subset \mathscr{D}_E$ and
therefore
\begin{align*}
 \mathscr{A}= \sigma(\mathscr{E}) = \delta(\mathscr{E}) \subset
 \mathscr{D}_E \qquad E\in \mathscr{E}',
\end{align*}
i.e. $\mathscr{D}_E = \mathscr{A}$ for $E\in \mathscr{E}'$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
 \mu(E\cap A) = \nu(E\cap A) \qquad E\in \mathscr{E}', A\in \mathscr{A}.
\end{align*}
In particular this equality holds for $E_n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. W.l.o.g.
the $(E_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are pairwise disjoint. Finally, for any
$A\in \mathscr{A}$
\begin{align*}
 \mu(A) = \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \cap A) =
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A\cap E_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu(A\cap E_n) = \dots
 \nu(A),
\end{align*}
which establishes the result.

My source is a german textbook, so I'm not sure if that's helpful. If you still have any questions regarding the proof feel free to ask. I'm very willing to discuss that further, since its also great practice for me.

So if the topological space contains open sets $(E_n)_n$ as above, the open sets uniquely define a measure.

I hope this helps if you didn't alsready know it.

PS: Please consider upvoting my aswer if you find it helpful, I still need reputation 50 to comment on questions.

BS

Comment: Your "system of sets" looks a lot like my 'semiring' definition, except with one fewer constraints. Having checked the relevant proofs in Dudley's textbook, the extra constraint seems non-trivial in deriving the uniqueness; could you explain how to obtain  your result or provide a source for it?

Comment: Getting there with this; can I ask (not that it's important) what the notation $\delta(\mathscr{E})$ means? Also, I presume that $\mathscr{E}$ is closed under countable (rather than just finite) intersections?

Comment: Assuming this is all correct, to extend this to an answer of my own question: the system of closed sets satisfies the conditions for $\mathscr{E}$, and so taking complements, the collection of open sets is always a determining class! That's the most general answer I could have hoped for, thank you!

Comment: To your first comment: $\delta(\mathscr{E})$ denotes the smallest Dynkin System which contains $\mathscr{E}$ and you only need that $\mathscr{E}$ is closed under finite intersections.

Comment: To your second comment: You need to additionally posit the existence of open sets $(E_n)_n$ as in the proof.

Comment: I did jump the gun a little, since in general measuring the open sets as complements of the closed sets won't work. However, since my definition of 'determining class' above requires finiteness on the chosen collection, and the entire set $X$ (or $\Omega$) is automatically both open and closed, the extra condition you mention is automatically satisfied for either the open or the closed sets!

Comment: But you then have to presuppose that the measure is finite on the open sets. This is not always true, since for example $\lambda(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$.

Comment: Edited original question slightly. I'm fine with assuming that the measure is finite on the open sets because I'm actually interested in probability (or, more generally, finite) measures. Your result is actually stronger than what I needed, but it does still apply to the case where $\mathscr{E}$ is the collection of intervals of finite length, as was the example in the textbook.