# Transition probability, Markov kernel ; computation $x_{n+1} = \alpha x_n + \beta \xi_{n+1}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

As part of my learning of Markov processes, I am trying to understand a few examples. I would like to compute the transition probability (kernel) of that process :

$$x_{n+1} = \alpha x_n + \beta \xi_{n+1} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
where the $\xi_n $ are iid normal $(0,1)$.

The answer shall be :

$$ P(x,dy) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 \pi} e^{ \frac{-(y-\alpha x)^2 }{2 \beta^2}  } dy  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

My problem is that, I am used to compute $P_{ij} = P(x_{n+1} = i | x_n = j)$. However, I am not used to the continuous case yet.

What I know is that $$P(x_n,A) = P(x_{n+1} | x_n \in A ) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$ for markov chains. My first step was to prove that $(1)$ is a M.C. (succesfully).

But then I am stuck.

So my question would be :

> how can one use $(2)$ to prove the answer $(*)$, and would it be
>   possible to start from the definition ( $ P(x_n,A) $ ) of transition probabilities to
>   compute $(*)$ ?

Any help is welcome. Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2)$ is incorrect. In your notation, it should be
$$P(x_n, A) = P(x_{n+1} \in A | x_n).$$
This notation can be confusing because it does not distinguish between the *transition kernel* $P$ (on the left-hand side) and the *probability* $P$ (on the right-hand side). Based on what you say,

> I am used to compute $P_{ij}=P(x_{n+1}=i|x_n=j)$.

you are comfortable thinking of $P_{ij}$ as a matrix. That is fine. With such a matrix, check that defining 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = j | X_n =i)=P_{ij}\tag{*}$$ implies $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} \in A | X_n = i) = \sum_{j\in A} P_{ij}$. Here I use $\mathbb{P}$ as a probability, to distinguish it from $P$ the matrix.

The same idea will hold for continuous-space Markov chains. Once you have shown that $(1)$ defines a Markov chain, you know it suffices to determine its transition kernel. Given $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, can you see that $\alpha x_n + \beta \xi_{n+1}$ is a random variable with mean $\alpha x_n$ and variance $\beta^2$? If so, then for any open set $A$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(x_{n+1} \in A | x_n) &= \mathbb{P}(\alpha x_n + \beta \xi_{n+1} | x_n) \\
&= \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\beta^2}}e^{-(y-\alpha x_n)^2 / 2\beta^2} dy.
\end{align*}
A shorthand notation for this is
$$\mathbb{P}(x_{n+1} \in dy | x_n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\beta^2}}e^{-(y-\alpha x_n)^2 / 2\beta^2} dy.$$

To understand this answer, it may first be a good idea to focus on why $(2)$ is wrong.

---

EDIT: I will use standard notation with random variables being denoted by capital letters.

To be clear, a discrete-space Markov chain is defined by the property
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n, \dots, X_1 = x_1) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n).\tag{**}$$
This is sometimes read as "the future (here, $X_{n+1}$), given the present ($X_n$), is independent of the past ($X_{n-1}, \dots, X_1$)". If you **define** $X_{n+1}$ through a transition kernel or matrix as I did in (*), then (**) will follow. However, you can compute 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n)$$
for any stochastic process, not just a Markov chain.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. The error in (2) was clearly a typo, thank you for notifying it.

Comment: small precision, why did you say "for any open set A"??? is it only defined for open sets ? (I have no mention of open/close/ compact in my stochastic calculus class).

Comment: The answer requires some measure theory. Strictly speaking, I couldn't use $A = \{y\}$ because $\mathbb{P}(x_{n+1} = y | x_n) = 0$ (hence the convention of $\in dy$ notation). However, you also cannot use *any* set $A$, because $\mathbb{P}(A)$ cannot be defined for all $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. I chose open sets because they are sufficiently "nice", but could also have chosen closed sets, intervals $(a,b), (a,b]$ or $[a,b]$, or other choices known as "measure determining classes" -- see e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866658/determining-class-of-a-general-borel-measure .

Comment: oh... I see. In my lecture notes one takes any set from the borel set, but taking open sets is enough thanks to pi lambda theorem. It makes sense, thank you !